# Boton Radio en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, radio

Cordial Saludo. que pena molestarlos , como hago para que solo quede activo al  que le de click, en java se hace asi : ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup(); bg.add(rdbtnSuma); --> pero aca en javaScript no he podido. Me echan una  mano, gracias.[image: Adjunto imagen con el codigo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red <br/>
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue <br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="green">Green
```

Si le pones a los `input` el mismo atributo `name` el navegador lo interpretará con que solamente uno de ellos puede estar activo al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Correcto , se variaba los indices y listo.  gracias--->